# Tsql (Microsoft SQL Server) - How to use " at time zone "

Tags: t-sql

I need convert dateTime with selected time zone, but i can't set it in variable.
code:

```
declare
    @date as datetime = '06/18/2023 20:00',
    @dateWithTimeZone as datetime

set @dateWithTimeZone = @date at time zone 'Middle East Standard Time';

print concat('@date = ', @date,'; @dateWithTimeZone = ', @dateWithTimeZone)
print datediff(second , @date, @dateWithTimeZone)
print datediff(second , @date, @date at time zone 'Middle East Standard Time')
```

1. - @date = Jun 18 2023  8:00PM; @dateWithTimeZone = Jun 18 2023  8:00PM
2. - 0
3. - 36000

It is look, like there is now way to save new date with selected time zone into variable @dateWithTimeZone, just by using  "at time zone" commmand?

Or I must use trick as bellow, or something like this:

```
set @dateWithTimeZone =  dateadd(second,datediff(second , @date at time zone 'Middle East Standard Time', @date at time zone 'My Time Zone' ), @date);
```

Comment: `@dateWithTimeZone` needs to be `datetimeoffset(n)` - not `datetime` - secondarily, the values don't acutally contain zone info, only a UTC offset. A UTC offset is not a timezone.

Comment: `'06/18/2023 20:00'` looks like `MM/dd/yyyy` which is locale-specific and non-portable (e.g. my computer and SQL Server default to `dd/MM/yyyy` so if you had `1/2/2023` it would be ambiguous and give unexpected results when run on other computers - you should always prefer ISO 8601-style (`yyyy-MM-dd`) to avoid this problem - _or_ set an explicit `SET DATEFORMAT {format}` at the start of your SQL script.

Comment: Thanks Dai, your brief comment make a good explanation to me,  note about data Type "datetimeoffset" and there is no time  zone info in dateTime helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use the `AT TIME ZONE` function to convert the datetime value to the desired time zone. Here's the updated code:

```
DECLARE @date AS datetime = '2023-06-18T20:00:00',
        @timezone AS varchar(50) = 'Middle East Standard Time',
        @dateWithTimeZone AS datetimeoffset

SET @dateWithTimeZone = @date AT TIME ZONE @timezone

PRINT CONCAT('@date = ', CONVERT(varchar(30), @date, 126), '; @dateWithTimeZone = ', CONVERT(varchar(30), @dateWithTimeZone, 126))
PRINT DATEDIFF(SECOND, @date, @dateWithTimeZone)
```

In this code, the `@date` value is provided in the ISO 8601 format `(yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss)`. Using a date format that is locale-specific can lead to unexpected results, especially when executing the script on different systems with different default date formats.

Comment: I changed data type to datetimeoffset and problem was solved. Thanks!